# Error importing PyMYSQL in AWS Lambda: 'No module named 'pymysql

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to import the module PyMYSQL for my Lambda function but I get the error:
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymysql'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "c60591d6-95c9-4f12-8909-05bd7a48261e",
"stackTrace": []
}

I have installed pymysql in the project directory and it didn't work. Then I tried to do it with Docker but still got the same error. The weird thing is that when I try to use the mysql.connector package and take the exact same approach as with the pymsql package I dont get the no module error but I get a timed out error when trying to connect to my database eventhough it does work when I try to run Locally. And yes I gave the lambda function the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole. Its just weird that when I run the python file from the command line in the project folder with the dependencies it does work but not in Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to manage dependencies in Lambda's Python environment is to use a Lambda Layer (i.e.: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html) 
Packaging dependencies for Lambda can sometimes be non-intuitive, and even the official guides might not always be up-to-date.

Here are some ready-to-use layers for Python, including PyMySQL: 
https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers